# Create a custom label

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following a [tutorial](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i1:-form-based-workflow) on how to build a blogging website based on Ruby on Rails. At the moment an article looks like below:

[image: Article 4]

The article has a title, a body, and comments below. The fields in which you enter your name and comment are currently entitled "AUTHOR NAME" and "BODY", respectively. These are 'default' names based on their corresponding attributes; see `comments_controller.rb` below.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @comment.article_id = params[:article_id]
    @comment.save
    redirect_to article_path(@comment.article)
  end

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:author_name, :body)
  end

end
```

The question is how to change the labels "AUTHOR NAME" and "BODY" into the custom labels "Your name" and "Your comment". The article is rendered by the view `show.html.erb`:

```
<h1><%= @article.title %></h1>
<p><%= @article.body %></p>
<h3>Comments (<%= @article.comments.size %>)</h3>
<%= render partial: 'articles/comment', collection: @article.comments %>
<%= render partial: 'comments/form' %>
<%= link_to "<< Back to Articles List", articles_path %>
<%= link_to "delete", article_path(@article), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Really delete the article?"} %>
<%= link_to "edit", edit_article_path(@article) %>
```

The display of the form is governed by the partial `_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>
  <ul>
  <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
    <li><%= error %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <!-- <%= f.label :author_name, "Your name" %><br /> -->
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <!-- <%= f.label :author_name, "Your Name"  %> -->
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

I've tried to implement the customized label using the commented-out lines, but this didn't work. How can I customize the labels?

Comment: When you used the commented out code, I assume you commented out the existing `f.label` lines? Also when you tried it, what happened? Did you still get the old labels? Something else? What went wrong?

Comment: Sorry for asking but, if my answer solved your question please mark it as accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do:

```
<%= f.label "Your name" %>
<%= f.text_field :title %>

<%= f.label "Your comment" %>
<%= f.text_area :body %>
```

The way you are doing it sets the label to what **:title** and **:body** correspond to in the model.

Comment: This solution doesn't appear to work: after updating the `_form.html.erb` as you suggest and refreshing the browser, I still see the same as before ("AUTHOR NAME" instead of "Your name").

Comment: It turns out there are two partials named `_form.html.erb`, one in `app/views/articles` and one in `app/views/comments`, and I was making the modifications in the "articles" one instead of the "comments" one. Both inserting the line `<%= f.label :body, "Your comment" %>` or `<%= f.label "Your comment" %>` works when done in the right partial.

Answer (score 0):

I would still keep the :title and :body on the form, but would add the custom label as second parameter.

```
<p>
    <%= f.label :title, "Your name" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :body, "Your custom label" %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
</p>
```